# pdf report using iTextSharp in C#

Tags: c#

I did pdf report using c# windows application using iTextSharp reference

`using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;`

I want to add a signature at the end of pdf file.
How can i add?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `TextField` object to contain the signature. Chapter 8 of iText in Action has information about filling out interactive forms.

[Here is an example of the TextField object getting used.](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=157)